# Always need Https to a particular route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have MVC3 application with SSL. I want particular page URL should always add Https. Can someone tell me how to do this. Below is the Route in Global file.

```
 routes.MapRoute("root22",
                "paybill",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "PayBill" });
```

One more thing if my URL has https in front than should all the paths in the page also use https or not necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to mess with the routing to accomplish this. Just use the `[RequireHttps]` attribute on your controller/actions.

```
[RequireHttps]
public ViewResult YourAction()
```

If it can, it will redirect to https. Your outgoing links don't have to use https, but when loading javascript, css, images, etc. then it should otherwise the user may get a mixed content security warning.

Answer (score 0):

Above attribute works fine if you want your whole website in https after redirecting using that particular action.

But you want to secure only a single page rather than whole website, just use below code.

http://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/More-fiddling-with-MVC3-and-https.aspx